# Snowflake - execution history of tasks with predecessors

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task

I have two tasks **T1** and **T2**. T1 runs every day at 7:00 hours and it is the **predecessor of T2**.

I am able to use the task execution history for T1. However, the history of T2 doesn't show up in the results.

Is there a way I can track whether the second task executed or not?

Best,
Vijay Prakash

---

**Update:**

Here is the query I used to query task execution status:

```
select *
  from table(information_schema.task_history(
    result_limit => 10,
    task_name=>'T2'));
```

Comment: Just covering basics: did T1 succeed? If not, T2 would not have executed at all. Otherwise, this is unexpected behavior.
Dinesh Kulkarni (PM, Snowflake)

Comment: T1 was successful and was able to confirm by looking at the task execution history.

Comment: Apparently, T2 did not run at all

Comment: Thanks, Dinesh for your inputs :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the above issue is, the order of starting the jobs was incorrect. I had `resumed` the first task (**T1**) before the second one (**T2**) which was why the second task was not executed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us a hit of how you are attempting to track tasks?
Should be able to track tasks and more using combinations of the below.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(information_schema.task_history(RESULT_LIMIT => 10000))

SELECT *
FROM TABLE(information_schema.QUERY_HISTORY_BY_WAREHOUSE(WAREHOUSE_NAME => 'WH_FOR_TASKS', RESULT_LIMIT => 10000))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Updated my question. 
I was always using that query. But I still don't see the results for T2.
Also, I don't think I will be able to find my task in query history within a decent amount of time :)

Comment: The result_limit parameter is extremely low.  What happens if you increase to the 10,000 maximum?

Comment: And maybe drop the task_name parameter just for kicks.

Comment: The task is scheduled to run just once per day and it was scheduled couple of days before. Hence, the result limit is set to 10. However, I will try with 10000. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I was able to figure out the issue.